# ascii file parsing based on position and length in line using python

Tags: python, parsing, csv, ascii

I would like to convert specific ascii file to csv.
This ascii file has own specification and I post below relevant fragments.

line A starts with code 66TP:

```
66TP        1003    54.437269600149717.012388003107655.5139691177756                :10.008677993245250.01231534739191
```

line B starts with C6NM:

```
C6NM0821.565823793411260.900167346000671.2812114953994820.81007696688170033                                1679475490.0000000001679475527.0000000001
```

As you see above individual values are not separated but their differentiation is
by position and length in line.

spec of line A:

```
1 Position   Length Data format Description of field

2   1           2   Type code   Record type code = 66
3   3           2   Derivation  Derivation code
4   5           16  Name        Point name
5   21          16  Latitude    Latitude
6   37          16  Longitude   Longitude
7   53          16  Distance    WGS84 ellipsoidal height at APC
8   69          16  Text 16     Feature code
9   85          1   GPS Method  Measurement method
10  86          1   Classification  Classification of the point
11  87          16  Distance    Horizontal precision
12  103         16  Distance    Vertical precision
```

spec of line B:

```
1   Position Length Data format Description of field
2   1           2   Type code   Record type code = C6
3   3           2   Derivation  Derivation code
4   5           2   Integer 2   Minimum number of satellites
5   7           1   Boolean     Relative DOPs
6   8               16  Scalar  PDOP (maximum)
7   24          16  Scalar  HDOP (maximum)
8   40          16  Scalar  VDOP (maximum)
9   56          16  Scalar  RMS
10  72          4   Integer 4   Number of GPS positions used
11  76          16  Distance    Horizontal standard deviation
12  92          16  Distance    Vertical standard deviation
13  108         4   Integer 4   Start GPS week
14  112         16  Scalar  Start GPS time in seconds to 3dp
15  128         4   Integer 4   End GPS Week
16  132         16  Scalar  End GPS time in seconds to 3dp
17  148         1   Monitor Status
```

my desired output is to merge both lines and would be like:

```
1003,54.4372696001497,17.0123880031076,55.5139691177756,0.009,0.012,8,1.6,0.9,1.28,20.8,033,1679,475490.0,1679,475527.0
```

and here's input file where I marked individual values with square brackets:

```
66TP        [1003]    [54.4372696001497][17.0123880031076][55.5139691177756]                :1[0.00867799324525][0.01231534739191]

C6NM[082][1.56582379341126][0.90016734600067][1.28121149539948][20.81007696688170][033]                                [1679][475490.000000000][1679][475527.0000000001]
```

Sorry for quite long post but I have no idea how could I describe it in shorter way.
I am an amateur beginner programmer and I'd like to ask you for any hint that let me start
handling such type of data.

Comment: Is CSV output being dictated to you? What will be done with the CSV?

Comment: It'll be then translated to html table as gps survey report.

Comment: Why not just output HTML directly then?

Comment: Because in the meantime I have to also perform calculations on latitude, longitude and height and then put everything to table. It is most simple way for me to retrieve data needed to computation and translate it to html as I am not skilled programmer.

Comment: Then you don't really want to output text at all; you just want to parse the data into some internal data structure which you then work with before outputting the HTML. The accepted answer shows how to do this; you don't get csv output, but instead a `list` of strings for each line.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know the position of each element on each line, use a [string slice](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) to grab each element.

For example,

```
type_code = linea[0:2]
(derivation, name) = (linea[2:4], linea[4:20])
```

To take this a step further, you could write a little function to split a line apart given a list of the lengths for the line.

### Code

```
def split_string_by_position(a_string, lengths):
    result = []
    position = 0
    for length in lengths:
        result.append(a_string[position:position+length])
        position = position+length
    return result


line = '66TP        1003    54.437269600149717.012388003107655.5139691177756'
lengths = [2, 2, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 1, 1, 16, 16]

print(split_string_by_position(line, lengths))
```

### Output

```
['66', 'TP', '        1003    ', '54.4372696001497', '17.0123880031076', '55.5139691177756', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

This just returns a list of the data elements.  You could takes this a step further by providing a variable name along with each length (`[[2,'type'], [2,'derivation'],...]`) and change the function around a little so it returns a `dict` instead so you could then access it by using `the_result['variable_name']`

A few ideas to play with.  http://learnpythonthehardway.org/ would be a good thing for you to work through so you learn the basics of the language.

Comment: thanks a lot, it seems quite simple but I have not yet such a broad perspective as my advnture with python is only one year long.

Comment: Right, I assumed based on your question.  Glad I could help and definitely give that learnpythonthehardway link some attention :)

Answer (score 1):

It kinda looks like this is whitespace separated, in which case you might be able to ignore the column numbers and just use line.split() to get a list of fields.

My to-table program might help also:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/to-table.html

Answer (score 1):

I thought it would be instructive (and possibly useful for some) to write this using a generator.

First the code:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/env python
  2
  3 def parser(str,len):
  4     '''Generate parsed chunks from str based on a list of lengths, len'''
  5     position = 0
  6     for l in len:
  7         yield str[position:position+l]
  8         position = position + l
  9
 10 line = '66TP        1003    54.437269600149717.012388003107655.5139691177756'
 11 lengths = [2, 2, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 1, 1, 16, 16]
 12
 13 lines = [ chunk for chunk in parser(line, lengths) ]
 14 print lines
```

Now you can use your parser anywhere you can use an iterator; such as how I used it on line 13 to shove all the strings into a list called lines.

You can also change your generator in interesting ways such as adding .strip() to the end of line 7.  Now your fields have the whitespace removed from the front and back of each.

With line 7 modified as described:

```
        yield str[position:position+l].strip()
```

You now get this *modified* output:

```
['66', 'TP', '1003', '54.4372696001497', '17.0123880031076', '55.5139691177756', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```